# "TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string" response to ruby on rails GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, get, typeerror

Help! I keep getting this error when doing a simple GET request on my Ruby on Rails app (using PostgreSQL):

```
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string>",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [
            {
                "exception_object_id": 26620,
                "id": 54,
                "trace": "app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:4:in `index'"
            }
        ],
```

It works for my Users GET request, but not for my Recipes GET request. Here's more info on my Recipes resource:

RECIPES SCHEMA:

```
  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "link"
    t.string "cuisine"
    t.string "ingredients"
    t.string "date"
    t.boolean "favorite"
    t.boolean "try"
    t.boolean "made"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

RECIPES CONTROLLER:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: Recipe.all, status: :ok
  end
end
```

RECIPES SERIALIZER:

```
class RecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :image, :link, :cuisine, :ingredients, :date, :favorite, :try, :made
end
```

ROUTES:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :recipes
  resources :users
end
```

It's weird because I have made several similar projects that have used just about identical back-end formatting/data, just this particular one is not working. I'm still fairly new to software engineering, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to look into perhaps this is a boolean issue, but not totally sure.

Comment: Ah! I think this does have to do with my boolean elements in my Recipes table. I took out the boolean elements in my schema & seed data and all worked. So.... what's the deal with booleans and this error message?

Comment: `try` is a predefined ruby method that you have used as an attribute for your model. that should be causing the issue here. try renaming the boolean `try` field to something else.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the boolean field being named `:try`

Could try longer names i.e.

```
is_favorite
wants_to_try / has_tried 
has_made
```